# Preventing a line break between an en dash and a paren

Tags: punctuation

When referring to a person who is still alive I give the birth year followed by an en dash all in parentheses, as in Jim Foo (1977--).  At times this results in a line break between the en dash and the right parentghesis.  Is there any way to prevent this so that Jim Foo (1977--) is all on the same line?

Comment: The easiest approach is probably to pack the whole date expression in a box: `\mbox{(1977--)}`

Comment: If you like one of the answers, it would be nice to mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

As Barbara already showed, you should put it in a `\mbox` to prevent the line break.

`\mbox` works like the content is in a box, that is not breakable.

If you want to make life easier, you could create your own command:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}    
\newcommand{\alive}[2]{{#1} \mbox{({#2}--)}}
\begin{document}
\alive{Jim Foo}{1977}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If the name is long, boxing name plus date could force the whole thing to a new line, wreaking havoc on the spacing of the paragraph.  While it's often possible to squeeze a single parenthesis into an existing line, things often don't go so well when a longer string is made unbreakable.

Comment: True, edited it :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Apart from boxing the whole date range, some other possibilities that may be more or perhaps less convenient, depending on the authoring requirements.

```
\documentclass{article}

\textwidth=2.9cm
\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

Jim Foo (1977--)


Jim Foo \mbox{(1977--)}

Jim Foo (1977\mbox{--})

Jim Foo (1977\nobreakdashes--)

\exhyphenpenalty=10000 % global affecting - and --- as well as --
Jim Foo (1977--)


\end{document}
```

Comment: Not quite exhaustive ... you didn't get the `\nobreakdash`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton `\nobreakdashes` with an s I'd forgotten about that, will add, thanks

Comment: @barbarabeeton added

Comment: But I don't remember a plural?  Did you change something?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I didn't remember either but the plural is in the format since 2004, borrowed from `amsmath`: % \begin{macro}{\nobreakdashes}
% \changes{v1.3}{2004/02/04}{(Macro added}
% \changes{v1.3a}{2004/02/15}{(Added spacefactor setting}
%    This idea is borrowed from the \textsf{amsmath} package but
%    here we define a robust command.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.  I either didn't know about that, or didn't remember it.  Is it in the "Companion"?

Comment: `\textendash` and `–` would work too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\nobreakdash` from `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\textwidth=2.9cm


\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

Jim Foo (1977\nobreakdash--)

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that `\nobreakdashes` is in the basic LaTeX format.  See comments following @DavidCarlisle's answer.